# ImageView is not loading correctly

Tags: android, image

In my Activity I have one ImageView

XML Code:

```
<!-- FOTO LATERAL! -->

                    <ImageView 
                        android:id="@+id/simbolo_raca"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

                         />
                   <Button 
                        android:id="@+id/button_save"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Ok. Seguinte Pergunta"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:paddingRight="30dip">
            </LinearLayout>
```

This is the Activity:

> ```
> public class QuestionarioActivityRaca extends Activity{
>  ImageView simbolo;
> int position;
> Button B_Save;
> List<Drawable> List_imagens = new ArrayList<Drawable>();
> @Override
> public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
> simbolo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.simbolo_raca);
> B_Save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_save);
> position = 0;
> List_imagens.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.p1));
> List_imagens.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.p2));
> List_imagens.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.p3));
> List_imagens.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.p4));
> loadNewImage(position);
> B_Save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>         public void onClick(View v) {
>          loadNewImage(position);
>          position++;
>         }
>     });
>  }
> // I Use this method to load the Image
> public loadNewImage(int Page)
> {    
>  new Thread(new Runnable(){
>             @Override
>             public void run(){
>               simbolo.post(new Runnable(){
>                     @Override
>                     public void run()
>                     {
>                         simbolo.setImageDrawable(List_imagens.get(Page));
>                     }
>                 });
>             }
>         }).start();
>  }
> ```

The first time I call this method, (position = 0) the image doesnt loads. After that, the image is loading correctly.

**How I have to do to load the image the first time?**

(I can not load the image in the XML using `android:src="@drawable/x"`) because the image could be different anytime.
EDITED!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues with the code sample you posted.

like writing int with a capital I.

```
Int position;
```

Not sending in a parameter with your method in the onClick:

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
     loadNewImage();
    }
```

And several more in both your XML and code.

Is there a spesific reason you want to run a new thread every time for this task?
If you really need a thread, you have to declare your int as final in the method.

However, you should get your desired result with the code-sample below.
You have to modify your onClick to send the appropriate int for whatever drawable you want to use.

Good luck.

```
public class testactivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    ImageView simbolo;
    int position;
    Button B_Save;
    List<Drawable> List_imagens = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_testactivity);
        simbolo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.simbolo_raca);
        B_Save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_save);
        position = 0;
        List_imagens.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_drawer));
        List_imagens.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_check));
        List_imagens.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_add_package));
        List_imagens.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_exception));
        loadNewImage(position);
        final Random rand = new Random();
        B_Save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                loadNewImage(rand.nextInt(4));
            }
        });
    }

    public void loadNewImage(final int page)
    {
        simbolo.setImageDrawable(List_imagens.get(page));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all before the button gets clicked you call this function to load the initial image with `loadNewImage(position);` when the button is clicked you call this function `loadNewImage();` i am guessing it works when the button is clicked because this `loadNewImage();` method is ok and `loadNewImage(int page);` is not ok, because they are two different function.

Solving your problem if you want an integer object use `Integer position` or else go with `int position` and please let go of the thread. now your code will work